# Firebase Data not showing on my RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I got this error today. When I watched a tutorial video about fetching firebase data to recycler view I followed the tutorial correctly. But when finish my app, I ran my app on my smartphone, after loging with Firebase Auth, Then my main activity doesn't show anything. just a white background and a toolbar.

This is my logcat. Can somebody help me?

```
11-26 10:10:27.724 30387-30488/com.example.ghifa.mrad2 D/FA: Connected to remote service
11-26 10:10:27.724 30387-30488/com.example.ghifa.mrad2 V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 4
11-26 10:10:32.844 30387-30488/com.example.ghifa.mrad2 V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
11-26 10:10:32.864 30387-30488/com.example.ghifa.mrad2 W/ContextImpl: forgetServiceDispatcher failed for:
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service not registered: com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzef@28094a2f
        at android.app.LoadedApk.forgetServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:1105)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.unbindService(ContextImpl.java:1873)
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.unbindService(ContextWrapper.java:562)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.stats.ConnectionTracker.unbindService(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzdr.disconnect(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzdr.zzcz(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzdr.zzc(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzds.run(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzw.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
        at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzbs.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Do you have the app connected with Firebase properly? Also, do you have inserted some data in Firebase that can be seen on recycler view at the same reference in your Firebase Database.

Comment: did you register your service in the manifest?

Comment: @PradyumanDixit yess i've done that

Comment: @Rainmaker how to do that? i don't know that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How to register service in the manifest

Add ServiceName under application tag in AndroidManifest.xml (naming in the example should be replaced by yours)

```
<service android:name="yourpackage.ServiceName" />
```

sample:

```
<service android:name=".MyFirebaseService" />
```

or you may need something like this with Intent-Filter, you don't provide any code so it is unclear what your are trying to do:

```
<service android:name=".MyFirebaseService" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
                </intent-filter>
            </service>
```

Comment: Excuseme, what "ServiceName" should I write?

Comment: so you should have a class that contains your Firebase service. You need to write the name of that class instead of ServiceName and the path to it instead of yourpackage

Comment: when you start typing class name in the quotes Android Studio will prompt you with import

Comment: Okay, I'll try it

Comment: sir I still confused, do you have an example? My firebase service is at Main.class

Comment: edited to give you more example but it is the full example ) below your activities declarations in the manifest you need to add the code I posted but replace the string in the name with your class name you have in you app. Your firebase service should be in some class right? And that has a name. You can revisit the tutorial you followed to see if you missed the manifest registration or you can look for the full tutorial if it is easier this way

Comment: do i have to write new user permision sir? Because when i whrote the service tag, it turns red

Comment: no permission, the service tag should be inside the application tags, so it will look like this 
<application> 
     <activity />
     <service />
</application>